# preg replace number with dot separator

Tags: php

i want to get value user id and album id with dot as separator

```
userId.albumId
1284939271971639.838074720820710
```

mycode

```
$id = '1284939271971639.838074720820710';

uid = preg_replace ('/d+./','',$id);

aid = preg_replace ('/.d+/','',$id);
```

Comment: Yea, and what do you want to do whit them, in regex `.` matches any single character, if you want a literal `.` then you must escape it `\.` unless its in a character class `[.]`

Comment: What you have with remove "stuff", perhaps you meant `explode('.', $id)`  which will create an array with 2 times split on the dot `.`

Comment: user id = 1284939271971639  album id = 838074720820710 how to get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do

```
$id = '1284939271971639.838074720820710';
preg_match('/(?P<id>\d+)\.(?P<album_id>\d+)/', $id, $match);

$id = $match['id'];
$album_id = $match['album_id'];
```

output

```
ID: 1284939271971639
Album ID: 838074720820710
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/01895f17bd1a08eb71fa967116389823edd55039)